# ssrs как изменить значение параметра при нажатии на текстовом поле

Tags: ssrs

У меня на отчете есть 6 Textbox которые показывают сумму записей принесенных в Dataset, каждый Textbox  свой Dataset.
Я хочу при нажатии на Textbox чтобы под всеми Textbox - ами отображалась таблица с данными относящимися к тому Textbox на который нажали.
Каждый из 6 Dataset приносит count(*) таблицы а соответственно таблица под всеми Textbox ами должна показать все данные.
Вообщем Textbox своего рода кнопка при нажатии на которую мне надо внизу этого отчета отобразить таблицу с данными.
Думал сделать через параметр, но не знаю как присвоить значение ему при нажатии на Textbox .
Буду очень признателен за помощь.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Ок решкние такое.
В Action того объекта на который мы кликаем, устанавливаем GoToReport b вызываем этот Report , добавляем Parametr со значением и вуаля, при нажатии на ссылку вызовется этот же report с нужным нам значением parametr и теперь зная значение мы можем делать все что угодно.
Спасибо всем!